# refresh table contents by running php script when button is clicked

Tags: php, soap

I have the following php and wish to know how I can achieve that the bottom part of the script is rerun with the new input value when the submit button is clicked.

I feel that my script needs just a final touch, but when you think another approach is preferred then don't refrain from making suggestions.

I do know how to assign a javascript to a button but here I wish to rerun only the bottom code (creating soap client, calling soap web service and applying xslt to the resulting XML) and wish to have that in php (mainly because I don't know the equivalent in ECMA script but also because the script takes care of placing the resulting table on the spot I wish to have it).

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
        "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />
    <title>Get element details</title>
    <style type="text/css">
        @import url("Swift.css");
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <br/>
<?php # httpCallExample2.php

    echo '<form action="httpCallExample2.php" method="post">
        <fieldset>
            <legend>Get element details</legend>
            <p>
                Element: <input name="element" type="text" size="12" maxlength="12" />&nbsp; &nbsp; <button type="submit" name="submit" value="update">Get details</button>
            </p>
        </fieldset>
    </form>
    ';
    echo '<br/>';

    $soapReq = new SoapClient('http://www.webservicex.net/periodictable.asmx?WSDL');
    $input = array ("ElementName" => $element);

    $result = $soapReq ->
        __soapCall("GetAtomicNumber",
            array(
                'parameters' => $input
            )
        );

    $XML = new DOMDocument();
    $XML -> loadXML ( $result -> GetAtomicNumberResult );

    $xslt = new XSLTProcessor();
    $XSL = new DOMDocument();
    $XSL -> load('showResults.xslt');
    $xslt -> importStylesheet( $XSL );

    echo $xslt -> transformToXML( $XML );

?>
</body>
</html>
```

Don't mind about the css file (that contains just some table layout stuff) but here's the xslt I use:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="html" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <table>
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th colspan="2">SOAP results</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <xsl:for-each select="//NewDataSet/Table/*">
                    <tr>
                        <td><xsl:value-of select="name()"/></td>
                        <td><xsl:value-of select="."/></td>
                    </tr>
                </xsl:for-each>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

The resulting page should look something like

[image: result]

Where I expect the bottom part to be filled after the input element has been given the value `Carbon` and the submit button has been clicked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had hoped that someone would help me out, but as always I could not leave it alone and went on to try to find a solution.
And I did: the trick is to reopen the php file and pass the element value to it, accessible by using the expression $_POST['element'] (or $_GET['element'], when using get method instead of post).

The end result that I reached was the following:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
        "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />
    <title>Get element details</title>
    <style type="text/css">
        @import url("Swift.css");
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <br/>
<?php
    echo '<form action="httpCallExample2.php" method="post">
        <fieldset>
            <legend>Get element details</legend>
            <p>
                Element: <input name="element" type="text" size="12" maxlength="12" />&nbsp; &nbsp; <input type="submit" value="Get details"/>
            </p>
        </fieldset>
    </form>
    ';
?>
    <br/>

<?php
    if (!empty($_POST['element'])) {
        $soapReq = new SoapClient('http://www.webservicex.net/periodictable.asmx?WSDL');
        $input = array ("ElementName" => $_POST['element'];

        $result = $soapReq ->
            __soapCall("GetAtomicNumber",
                array(
                    'parameters' => $input
                )
            );

        $XML = new DOMDocument();
        $XML -> loadXML ( $result -> GetAtomicNumberResult );

        $xslt = new XSLTProcessor();
        $XSL = new DOMDocument();
        $XSL -> load('showResults.xslt');
        $xslt -> importStylesheet( $XSL );

        echo $xslt -> transformToXML( $XML );
    }
?>
</body>
</html>
```

resulting in just the input form first, and when entering (for example) `potassium` and clicking the button, this gives

[image: result2]

of course, it is possible to enter the posted value into the input element again.

Comment: Is this really refreshing part of the page or is it just reloading the page with different data?

Comment: It is a reload with an additional value passed to the php file by the http POST request. The effect is the same as refreshing the bottom part (and wiping out the input value), though, so I am happy with it for this moment :-).

Comment: Your question made it seem like you wanted to do something with AJAX, which is creating a partial page reload. You can always use POST or GET to pass new variables to the script and change the output based on them. That's, I would say, the very foundation of web programming.

Comment: And so it is. But these are my first steps in this area and it's all kind of new to me. Thanks for thinking along though.